# Visual force Page and VF Component Communication

Tags: java, components, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I am trying to insert component's form record from parent visual force page's button click.

I am using virtual class to achieve this.

Please visit the below link for Controller Component Communication help : http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Controller_Component_Communication

In above example, he is increasing the value of a variable that is already in component.

My requirement is that i have to get user input from the page.

please see the below code, so you can understand the issue :

Thanks

Comment: There is too much code, and i do not understand your problem?

Comment: Acutally i have a VF page that contains a componet. i have to save user input from component, on clicking of save button that is in Main VF page.

For this i am using virtual class. but i am not able to capture record from component.

Comment: But the saveComponent method works good and you can upsert crfQues without problems? What do you want exactly after the user clicks on the button "Submit Test" and the new record (crfQues) is saved? I just trying to understand where can i help :)

Comment: If you see saveComponent method, there is a statment "system.debug('lstQuesAnsWrapper inside save() : '+lstQuesAnsWrapper);" here i am printing the values, that i am getting from component. but the value is comming null. that should be the value that i am entered in component field.

There is

Comment: Did you tried this: `public List<QuestionAnswerWrapper> lstQuesAnsWrapper { get; set; }`

Comment: Yes, i have tried but its not working. i cant use get;set; here because when my component is loaded, i have to query in database based on the value that i am passing in component as Argument. that was not possible in controller, thats why i used getlstQuesAnsWrapper method instead of "get;". Right now i added setlstQuesAnsWrapper also. but now also unable to get value.